# 'detailsUserTitle' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

DropDownList keeps returning this error :(

Here is my aspx code

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="username" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2">
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="username" SortExpression="username">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("username") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="title">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="detailsUserTitle" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("title") %>' DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select Title</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Mr">Mr</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Mrs">Mrs</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Miss">Miss</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Ms">Ms</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorTitle" 
                    ControlToValidate="detailsUserTitle" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Title is a required field" 
                    Text="*" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="-1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("title") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("title") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

I have been looking online for advice, but there hasn't been a conclusive one that helped me. Please help. I didn't add any code behind related to this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the DDL attribute `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("title") %>'`

Your SQL DataSource "**SqlDataSource1**" may not be returning any of the values from Mr, Mrs, Miss or MS.

If **Title** field has a different value you get this error

**UPDATE**

You may validate your Title string as below before binding. But, I wouldn't recommend this. I prefer if you could validate the values before retrieving from your data source. The ideal solution would be to bind the DropDownList with same set of values before finding the values in it. then you won't miss anything.

Here's the quick fix. :-)

```
SelectedValue='<%# (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Bind("title")) || "Mr, Mrs, Miss, MS".IndexOf(Bind("title")) > -1) ? Bind("title") : "-1" %>'
```

**UPDATE 2**
Here you go :-D

```
SelectedValue='<%# (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Eval("title")) || "Mr, Mrs, Miss, MS".IndexOf((string)Eval("title")) > -1) ? (string)Eval("title") : "-1" %>'
```

Please accept the answer if it resolves your issue. All the best!

Comment: The SQL Datasource does have values of Mr, Mrs, Miss and Ms from different records. 

Maybe I should do a binding check? But I don't know how to do it in this case

How can I check if Title has a different value?

Comment: Hey Sam, thank you for the quick fix. But I get a Compilation error from that quick fix It says:

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Hmmm, can you try Eval("title") instead of Bind("title")?

Comment: Hey Sam, the only way I can add Eval to SelectedValue is if I put it in the last Bind like so
SelectedValue='<%# (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Bind("title")) || "Mr, Mrs, Miss, MS".IndexOf(Bind("title")) > -1) ? Eval("title") : "-1" %>'

I receive the same Compilation Error ~ Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean? You should be able to replace all Bind statements with Eval

Comment: Oh, it's because it had red errors on them. I was able to go through but came up with a compilation error

CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Ok that's a different issue. Cast Eval("title") as (string)Eval("title") within string.IsNullOrEmpty function

Comment: Hey Sam, Like this?

(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)Eval("title") || "Mr, Mrs, Miss, MS".IndexOf(Eval("title")) > -1) ? Eval("title") : "-1" %>'

If so I get these errors in the compiler
1. Invalid expression term 'string'
2. ) expected
3. Invalid expression term ')'
4. ; expected
5. Only assignment, call increment, decrement, await and new object expressions can be used as a statement
6. The best overloaded method match for 'string.IndexOf(string)' has some invalid arguments
7. Argument1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'
8. Only assignment, call increment, decrement, await and new..

Comment: EEK! You got me haha. Yeah i'm new to ASP.net

The update 2 provides the same error as in the beginning
'detailsUserTitle' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

Comment: It can't be. Now if Eval("title") returns null, empty string or anything other than a value in your DDL it selects the first option. I.e. "Select Title". The only possibility is DDL may not be populated when you try to bind the values. To test this add SelectedValue='Mr' instead of any binding code. If you get the same error that means at the data binding time your DDL doesn't have any list items. Then we;ll have to look into another method.

Comment: I get a parsing error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The 'SelectedValue' property cannot be set declaratively.

Comment: Yup I did :) When I press edit in my details view. I get the error 

'detailsUserTitle' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value