# Regex for Mr, Miss, Mrs and Ms

Tags: regex

Is there a way where I can find if any of these strings are entered. I want to see if the user entered "Mr", "Miss", "Mrs" or "Ms".

I have tried `/^(Miss|Mr|Mrs|Ms)$/` but to no avail.

The context is that I have a text box that users should enter their title into.

I want users to only Enter "Mr", "Miss", "Mrs", and "Ms". If they enter anything else, throw an error.

Comment: Dr, Rev, Sir, Lord, Dame, Lady... This may be one of those questions where a little more context could help

Comment: Works for me... http://rubular.com/r/WO7fLbcTMW

Comment: Here's a great tool for testing regexes - http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: I'm using a RegularExpressionValidator in ASP.net to check whether users entered their title right. If Miss/Mr/Mrs/Ms was not entered then throw an error. UMM is there a way to do an inverse of that regex I did?

Comment: Use a drop down menu instead of a text box.

Comment: @JoshCaswell hey Josh, thanks for replying. The thing is I get a horrendous problem that I couldn't solve, even with looking at lots of solutions if I implement a drop down list

So I've reverted to a textbox

Comment: Did you try [without the delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13626639/3110638) `/` ?

Comment: That's like saying that your lawnmower won't start, so you're cutting the grass with a pair of scissors. Fix your lawnmower. This is going to be a _terrible_ user experience -- reading your mind to figure out _exactly_ which honorifics you planned for and _exactly_ how you spelled them (no period/full stop, e.g., which should be present in American English but perhaps not other dialects).

Comment: @Jonny5 You are a legend. Thank you so much (Y) I wish i can give you reddit gold

Comment: @JoshCaswell I agree, i've been searching for the answer for 2 days and I just can't seem to get it. I really regret doing this method, but it's the only way that works.

Comment: You could probably ask about your problems with the combo box here too.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Here it is :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718960/detailsusertitle-has-a-selectedvalue-which-is-invalid-because-it-does-not-exis

Comment: If you limit the title like that, you'll get complaints from customers. People with titles tend to be picky about them. It's almost like they have a sense of... [puts on sunglasses] ...entitlement.

Comment: @MattGibson Oh so true oh so true

Answer (score 2):

Maybe all you need to do is to get rid of the `$` at the end and replace it with a `\b` so that if I enter 'Mr John' you can recognize it.

Example link: http://regexr.com/39faa

Comment: i think he need to remove the both anchors.

Comment: That depends actually if it's a regex to match the beginning of the line, or anywhere. If anywhere the `^` should also be replaced by `\b`

Answer (score 1):

A more compact version of your regex might be:

```
/^(M(?:is)?s|(?:Mrs?))/
```

Have look at [this demo](http://rubular.com/r/HLFjX2CDTH).

As mentioned in another answer's comment, if the search string can lie in the middle of the string as well then remove `^` from pattern.

Comment: But sometimes less is more, I think I prefer the one that lists the options.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(Mr|Mrs|Mr|Dr|Er)\.[A-Za-z]+$/;
```

Here `^(Mr|Mrs|Mr|Dr|Er)` will check for the starting of the string.

`\.` will allow a dot after Title

And then there can be any word or letter so array of words.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\bM(?:rs?|s|iss)\b
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/jCobDt6ksE)

Comment: This will match `M` and `Mis`.